# Node.js/JavaScript/SQL - order of sequences

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript, I just know Java and C.

I'm currently writing a bot for my own Discord-Server and I have a huge problem:

With my Java knowledge I thought, that this code will work:

```
function eintraegeVon(authorID)  {
var sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE discord_id = ?";
var query = con.query(sql, authorID, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
        return -1;
    }
    return result.length;
});
console.log("Test if this is reached in the program");
}
```

I thought that the line `console.log("Test...")` will never be reached, because before this line, in the query-sequence is a return-command -> function is finished. Or, if it exist an error, it will execute before that with return value -1.

When I add some console-writing-commands for debug I see, that first, the "test..." command is shown, than the rest of the function, who called the function "`eintraegeVon`" is continued, and at the end, the "return result.length"-command is done.

Why is this so?

I read something about it, that node.js can be asynchronous, but why this function is not processed one command after each command like in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function definition has 3 instructions, let us take a look at each one.

1st instruction is just a variable declaration: 
`var sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE discord_id = ?";`

in 2nd instruction has a lot going on, let us dissect it at the end, but for now, let us simplify it as: "*Please execute this function for me and store the returned value in the var named query*"

your 3rd instruction is `console.log(...)`

So you see, it is doing nothing different from what a java program would've done. Note, you are not calling the return in the "main" method, you are calling "return" from some *other* method.

Now, let us dissect your 2nd instruction, as that introduces you to a concept which you may not have seen in Java.

```
var query = con.query(sql, authorID, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
        return -1;
    }
    return result.length;
});
```

You are asking javascript to call a `function` con.query, with 3 arguments:

1. SQL Query to execute
2. parameter for that query
3. a `callback` function to call *after* the con.query has done its work. This is the concept which can trigger your confusion. I highly recommend reading the "you don't know JS" book. It is also on Github if you cannot afford it. [link to chapter on callbacks](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md)

Let me know if you would still prefer some explanation of callbacks when compared to a language like Java. I will add some comparison points.

Comment: 1. ah ok, so how can i see/know, which function-call is executed "normally" and which one is called"callbacked"?   2. Ill read ur link soon :) 3. exist a fast solution for this specific problem from me?

Comment: for #1 --> if you are calling a function like: `calculate()` it is executed synchronously (might be complicated by async/await, but I assume it is not a concern right now).
`Callbacks` generally have the syntax like: `someFunction(arg1, arg2, someotherFunction)`, in this case somefunction is a "normal" call and someotherfunction is a callback

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, node is asynchronous and 'Test... ' log is executed before you get answer from database. The function you've passed in query is executed after you get an answer from database.

Answer (score 0):

The query function is executed asynchronously and the execution continues, that is why the message get's printed first. You should get familiar with that aspect of javacript and node.js since you are gonna meet it everywhere. Check this tutorial: [Understanding Async Programming in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)
  Also check the latest methods in handling async code: [Callbacks, Promises and Async/Await](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/callbacks-promises-and-async-await-ad4756e01d90)

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous and it is non-blocking.It means, it does not wait for function to be ended and it will jump to next line or the next function. But previous function calls also return back when it ended. By using callback functions, sequential execution can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, seems you are not using ORM as you are new in JS I would suggest you to use suitable ORM with your database. Here you are trying to fetch a user by id.

In ORM you will get function with callback or promise where you will find the flow what should you do how should you go.

Your function definition has 3 instructions, let us take a look at each one.

1st instruction is just a variable declaration:  var sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE discord_id = ?";

in 2nd instruction has a lot going on, let us dissect it at the end, but for now, let us simplify it as: "Please execute this function for me and store the returned value in the var named query"

your 3rd instruction is console.log(...)

So you see, it is doing nothing different from what a java program would've done. Note, you are not calling the return in the "main" method, you are calling "return" from some other method.

Now, let us dissect your 2nd instruction, as that introduces you to a concept which you may not have seen in Java.

```
var query = con.query(sql, authorID, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
        return -1;
    }
    return result.length;
});
```

after that this line won't execute

```
console.log("Test if this is reached in the program");
```

Put it before return to see.

Yeah I know you are trying to console that to know is it finished execution or not for that you can use callback which will return you either an error or result.

But if possible then try ORM to handle those.